# How to seed multiple instances of AngularJS models with data?

Tags: angularjs

I have a webapp with 10-15 modules on a single page.  Each module displays different types data and allows paging, filtering, etc...

I currently asynchronously load each module with data, but this feels choppy and the app  updates at different speeds, and page loads can take between 5 and 10 seconds to fully populate when the AJAX calls return their promise.

What is the best way to seed the data on the page in order to avoid having to load each module separately.  They will still paginate and filter, via AJAX calls to the data source, but I would like to them appear fully populated when the page loads.

Comment: Check out ng-cloak I think it covers your needs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak if not perhaps you could just use an ng-hide/ng-show and just use a boolean to turn the display on after all your promises return

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, the only drawback I see is that the page would be partially blank, and then all blink into place once the loading is completed.

Comment: Perhaps you can show some nice loading screen with a spinner or progress bar and then switch to showing your elements with the data populated.

Comment: You can also try to generate the initial view on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain together some promises and wait for them all to complete using $q.all().

> **[$q (service in module ng)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)**
>
> *Methods - all(promises)*
>
> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index in the promises array. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be resolved with the same rejection.

Or you could just show a spinner while everything is loading with something like this: https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker.

Here is a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XlYz6j?p=preview